# Fluent NHibernate cascading delete convention for aggregate roots

Tags: c#, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, conventions, automapping

Question is: how to write convention that prevents deleting entity reference if it inherits from type `Root`?

---

I'm using fluent nhibernate and it's auto mapping feature. Turned on cascading delete by default.

Everything was really cool until I finally hit case when I need to actually delete aggregate root that references another one.

I got roots `User` and `Application`. `User` registers `Applications`. If it's registered by mistake, there is small time gap in which `User` with role `Admin` can remove it (I'm kind a sure I won't ever need that data).

When `User` removes `Application`, because of cascading delete, nhibernate removes `User` itself (what an irony...).

---

I'm unsure how to specify SaveUpdate cascading for Application->User association only:

[image]

---

Does the trick:

```
m.References(x=>x.RegisteredBy).Cascade.SaveUpdate(); //RegisteredBy.Type==User
```

Additionally, told fnh where to look for overrides:

```
var m=new AutoPersistenceModel(storeCfg);
m.UseOverridesFromAssembly(assembly);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can override behaviour of cascading for Application->User association. You need to set SaveUpdate() instead of all-delete-orphan. 
To do this you will need to implement `IAutomappingOverride<Application>`

Comment: I'm a bit confused again. Added picture to my question.